# Reg ex to match everything between two tags

Tags: regex

I have a string similair to this

```
<td><p>alakjsdlajsdlkj</p><p><b>asdkjalsdkjaskldj</b></p><p>asdjlaksjdlaksjd</p></td>
```

What is the regular expression to grab everything between the  tags?

I want to grab the following (including the HTML)

```
<p>alakjsdlajsdlkj</p><p><b>asdkjalsdkjaskldj</b></p><p>asdjlaksjdlaksjd</p>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an XML/HTML parser? Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't accomplish this with regular expressions. They just aren't descriptive/powerful enough, mainly in that there is no mechanism to keep track of how many of something it has seen. In short, this is because the regex mechanism has no notion of a stack (it represents finite state machines, not pushdown automata).

For example, consider the pattern `<p>(.*)</p>`. If you used greedy mode (match as much as possible) and have a string like `<p>first</p><p>second</p>`, the match will be `first</p><p>second`. If you went with non-greedy mode (make the smallest match possible) and get a string like `<p><p>stuff</p></p>`, you'll be rewarded with the match `<p>stuff`. So neither mode covers all cases (or any case) well.

As @kristopher points out, it's possible to have a pattern that avoids including another tag inside the match, but this will only match innermost tags.

To do what you want robustly, you'll need an actual parser. Several html parsing solutions have been created by others, or for simple parsing needs, you might be able to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

if your tags nest this gets messy fast.

are you unable to use an html parser library? It would be FAR better to do so.

```
<([^>]+)>([^<]+)</\1>
```

gets you 
any string wrapped in angle brackets 
plus any characters up until the next tag

this doesn't handle nested or mismatched tags though

```
<div>test <b>nested</b></div>
```

will only catch the 
    < b >
not the div since the < div > will encounter the start of the < b > before encountering the end of its own tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use an [HTML parser](https://www.google.com/search?q=HTML%20parser%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and the td and ending td are at the beginning and end of the string:

```
^<td>(.*)</td>$
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it should just match the outermost tags and return the inner string in the group

```
^<\w+>(.*)</\w+>$
```

But it does not checks for correct nesting etc. Use an appropriate framework if possible.